# Combining IF Functions or what works better

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Trying to figure out how to show the value from a cell when doing IF.OR function.

Here is my function (not working):

```
=IF($P$14="";"";IF(OR($P14="PALLET";"$H14";"$L14"))
```

The function should show empty if empty, but show the value of cell `H14` if `P14=Pallet`, while if different, show the value of cell `L14`.

Thank to all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an `OR` for that:

```
=IF($P$14="";"";IF($P14="PALLET";"$H14";"$L14")
```

`OR` is to return `TRUE` when at least one of several conditions is true. You just need to return `TRUE` for a single condition (`P4="PALLET"`)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Trim is incase you have a cell of spaces

```
IF(P14="Pallet",H14,IF(TRIM(P14)="","",L14))
```